# Avoid repeating to make the same call in each ViewController

Tags: swift

I have implemented `NetworkObserver` class and all of my viewcontroller checking the `statusupdate` and display an alert respectively. However, I am repeating the code in each and every `UIViewController`. Is there a better approach?

```
protocol NetworkObserver: class {
  func statusDidChange()
}

final class NetworkManager {

}
```

**ViewControllerA**

```
extension ViewControllerA: NetworkObserver {
  
  func statusDidChange() {
      self.showAlert(message: "Require pull to refresh")
    }
}
```

**ViewControllerB**

```
extension ViewControllerB: NetworkObserver {
  
  func statusDidChange() {
      self.showAlert(message: "Require pull to refresh")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give `statusDidChange` a default implementation by extending the protocol.

```
protocol NetworkObserver: class {
    func statusDidChange()
}

extension NetworkObserver where Self: UIViewController {
    func statusDidChange() {
        self.showAlert(message: "Require pull to refresh")
    }
}
```

Then you'll be able to delete `statusDidChange` from all of your individual view controllers because they already have the default implementation just by adopting the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
class BaseVC:UIViewController{ 
   func statusDidChange() {
      self.showAlert(message: "Require pull to refresh")
  }
}
```

Then

```
class FirstVC:BaseVC{ 

}
```